# belongs_to with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails noob and have a question. I have a feed aggregator that is organized by this general concept:

Feed Category (books, electronics, etc)
Feed Site Section (home page, books page, etc)
Feed (the feed itself)
Feed Entry

So:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feeds
  has_many :feed_entries, :through => :feeds, :limit => 5
  validates_presence_of :name
  attr_accessible :name, :id
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feeds
  has_many :feed_entries, :through => :feeds, :limit => 5
  attr_accessible :name, :id
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :categories
  belongs_to :sections
  has_many :feed_entries
  validates_presence_of :name, :feed_url
  attr_accessible :name, :feed_url, :category_id, :section_id
end

class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feed
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :section
  validates_presence_of :title, :url
end
```

Make sense? Now, in  my index page, I want to basically say... If you are in the Category Books, on the Home Page Section, give me the feed entries grouped by Feed...

In my controller:

```
def index
    @section = Section.find_by_name("Home Page")
    @books = Category.find_by_name("Books")
end
```

In my view:

```
<%= render :partial => 'feed_list',
           :locals => {:feed_group => @books.feeds} 
-%>
```

This partial will spit out the markup for each feed entry in the @books collection of Feeds. Now what I need to do is somehow combine the @books with the @section...

I tried this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'feed_list',
           :locals => {:feed_group => @books.feeds(:section_id => @section.id)} 
-%>
```

But it isn't limiting by the section ID. I've confirmed the section ID by using the same code in the console...

Make sense? Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble following.  What is the difference between Category and Section?  Would just adding a find in the controller such as `@feeds = Feed.find :all, :conditions => [ "section_id = ? and category_id = ?", @section.id, @page.id ]` do what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
:locals => {:feed_group => @books.feeds.all(:conditions => {:section_id => @section.id})}
```

Comment: From her description, this sounds like it would work.  It feels wrong to have this logic in the view when you have all of the information required in the controller, so it may be better to build @feeds there first.

Comment: @Awgy - agreed. I put this back in the controller. Thanks!